# Javascript animated counter isn't specific enough

Tags: javascript, math

So I am making a counter that works really fine it's just not specific enough:

```
<div class="sosm youtube">
            <h3 class="names">Youtube</h3>
            <h3 class="number" fame="60000">0000</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sosm twitter">
            <h3 class="names">Twitter</h3>
            <h3 class="number" fame="30000">0000</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sosm facebook">
            <h3 class="names">Facebook</h3>
            <h3 class="number" fame="50000">0000</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sosm likedin">
          <h3 class="names">Linkedin</h3>  
          <h3 class="number" fame="1000">0000</h3>
        </div>
```

and here's the javascript code that I used:

```
const number = document.querySelectorAll('.number')
const speed =300

number.forEach(data => {
   const fame = data.getAttribute('fame')
   const speedc = fame/speed
   const increment = () =>{
       let display = +data.textContent

       if(display < fame){
            data.innerHTML = Math.ceil(display + speedc)
            console.log(display)
            setTimeout(increment, 1)
       }else{
           display = display
       }

   }
   increment()
})
```

When I run this animated counter the final number should've matched the "fame" attribute. While most of the numbers matched but some didn't, how do I make it more specific?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if the result of `display + speedc` is greater than `fame`. In that case use `fame` instead.

Comment: For custom attributes like `fame` you should better use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Comment: Every time you do `Math.ceil` it introduces a rounding error when the number is fractional.